# Returning mutliple sql database values from php to android

Tags: php, sql, json

I am trying to read my sql database through php and return the 'status' of entry to my android application in eclipse(java).

```
<?php

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_uid = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "mytestdatabase";

$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_uid,$db_pass) or die('could not connect');
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM aircraft_status";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
$status=$rows['Status'];                    
echo json_encode($status);}

?>
```

I have the query working and returning:

```
"0""0""0""0""0""0""2""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0"
```

But I want to use each of these as an individual variable in eclipse. 
Eg.
a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0, e=0, f=0, g=2, h=0, i=0, j=0, k=0, l=0, m=0, n=0, p=0, q=0

Can't find any information except for running this 16 times with a single entry each time, which seems very inefficient.

Please help this very novice programmer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you do this you will at least get an array returned:

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
    $status[] = $rows['Status'];                    
}
echo json_encode($status);
```

If for example you have a `name` column on your database, as you did a `SELECT *` which means select all the columns from the table, you could do this to make the data a little more useful:

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
    $status[] = array( $rows['name'] => $rows['Status'] ); 
}
echo json_encode($status);
```

Comment: Thanks! That is the direction i want to go. I may be pushing it, but now that each name has a integer how do i transfer this to my android java on eclipse?

Comment: [{"A70-870":"0"},{"A70-871":"0"},{"A70-872":"0"},{"A70-873":"0"},{"A70-874":"0"},{"A70-875":"0"},{"A70-876":"2"},{"A70-877":"0"},{"A70-878":"0"},{"A70-879":"0"},{"A70-880":"0"},{"A70-881":"0"},{"A70-882":"0"},{"A70-883":"0"},{"A70-884":"0"},{"A70-885":"0"}]

Comment: @Riggs78 Ask that as a new question, or we will get into trouble from the stack police. The reason being, so that the new question and hopefully the new answer can also be found and used by others in the same situation.